# Not able to load applet in jsp in chrome browser after deprecating NPAPI in Chrome

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I embedded applet in to the jsp page but after chrome update it is not working due to depreciated the applet in chrome. So what are the ways to achieve this task. In my application I use USB Token for signing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed applet in the browser as NPAPI is deprecated. You can achieve this task only by creating a separate client application by linking it to the server .

Comment: Thanks I will try same thing but It may be have some security loop holes.

Comment: Could you expand your answer so i can achieve this things.

Comment: You can make your GUI as in JavaFX or swing or even as an applet and convert it into an executable file , create installer and after that can run it.It depends on you how you want to use it for your application and how you connect to the installer with your application.